# Set accordion default to collapsed

Tags: javascript, accordion, collapsable

There's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/AFMPW/).

I'm trying to have the panels collapsed on default by adding...

```
$container.active(false);
```

And it does collapse the panels, but then it also disrupts other jquery plugins on the page.

Here's the full script:

```
(function() {

    var $container = $('.acc-container'),
        $trigger   = $('.acc-trigger');

    $container.hide();
    $container.active(false);
    $trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();

    var fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true);
    $trigger.css('width', fullWidth);
    $container.css('width', fullWidth);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e) {
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Resize
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true)
        $trigger.css('width', $trigger.parent().width() );
        $container.css('width', $container.parent().width() );
    });

})();
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have `Unknown TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'active'`. jQuery objects indeed don't have such method. Did you forget to include some plugin?

Comment: Nope. When I remove what I thought the solution was... `$container.active(false);`, the accordion works just fine. All I want is to not have the first panel open on default. I want them closed until clicked. If you comment out that line, you'll see what I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write some negative code. Remove your fix attempt, it was causing an error, thats why all other scripts stopped working.

```
$container.active(false);
```

Then remove the next line. Here first item of the accordion was expanded:

```
$trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();
```

Comment: That forced the panes to start closed. Then I had to add some inline CSS because the panels automatically extended horizontally, but it's good. Now, once I open the panels, I can't seem to close them.

Comment: @webfrogs original works the same. If this is an issue consider opening a separate question.